# Is there a way to read a truncated gif with PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to read in a GIF image with in Python that appears to work fine with browsers, but not with PIL. With the code below

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('flow.gif')
im = im.convert('RGB')
```

I get the following traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-6f71a00ad83b> in <module>()
      1 im = Image.open('flow.gif')
----> 2 im = im.convert('RGB')

/Users/.../site-packages/PIL/Image.pyc in convert(self, mode, data, dither, palette, colors)
    672                 return self.copy()
    673 
--> 674         self.load()
    675 
    676         if data:

/Users/.../site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.pyc in load(self)
    218                             break
    219                         else:
--> 220                             raise IOError("image file is truncated (%d bytes not processed)" % len(b))
    221 
    222                     b = b + s

IOError: image file is truncated (241 bytes not processed)
```

Here's the image: [image: problematic gif image]

I tried to use ImageMagick to convert the image to another format, but ImageMagick does not like it either. If I use Preview in OSX it has no problems reading the image, like the browsers. It seems like the apps can handle such issues, but not PIL. Any ideas on a workaround or solution?

Comment: If re-saving it with gimp/browser doesn't work, you could try `pillow`.

Comment: I tried Pillow and had an error as well. I'm a bit surprised that there are no Python packages that can parse a GIF image like this, while Preview, Chrome and many other apps don't complain. Obviously, they are optimized for such events.

Comment: Unless you have a huge batch of broken gifs, just save it to a valid format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opencv can handle gifs. it treats them as a container of frames like any other video or stream.
if you have it installed, you can do following:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
gif = cv2.VideoCapture('file.gif')
ret,frame = gif.read() # ret=True if it finds a frame else False. Since your gif contains only one frame, the next read() will give you ret=False
img = Image.fromarray(frame)
img = img.convert('RGB')
```

Answer (score 5):

Somewhere before your code block, simply add the following:

```
from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

I tested this against the photo you provided, and I was able to work with the image without any problems.

EDIT: It looks like this helps for the version of PIL bundled with Pillow ("pip install pillow"), but may not work for default installations of PIL